# How can i make that my application will check and get specific email subject?

Tags: c#, email

I have this class that send emails. I log in using my isp email and send it to my gmail email.
Now i want to do that when someone will download/get my application it will check each 1 minute for my gmail account address for a specific email with a specific subject so the email subject will be like a code for example the email subject will be: 16765645

Once the application downloaded the email i want to display the email content in a textBox and also to write on a text file the email content. Also i want that the application will check the email time download after it was downloaded so the application will not download the same email all the time.

This is how i'm sending emails today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DannyGeneral;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen
{
    class SendEmail
    {
        private MailMessage photosmessage;
        public bool textfilessendended;
        public bool photossendended;
        Label lbl1;
        Label lbl3;
        Button SendLogFile;
        MailMessage message;
        MailMessage docmessage;
        public int timerdelay;
        public Timer timer3;

        public SendEmail(Label label2, Label label3, Button slf, int timerd, Timer timer)
        {
            textfilessendended = false;
            photossendended = false;
            lbl1 = label2;
            lbl3 = label3;
            SendLogFile = slf;
            timerdelay = timerd;
            timer3 = timer;
        }

        public void SendLogger()
        {
            string log_file_name = "logger.txt";
            string logger_file_to_read = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\log";
            string LoggerFile = Path.Combine(logger_file_to_read, log_file_name);
            try
            {
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "User " + (char)0xD8 + " Name",
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("test@test.net");
                message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Body = "Please check the log file attachment i have some bugs.";
                string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
                message.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
                message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Subject = "Log File For Checking Bugs" + someArrows;
                message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(LoggerFile, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
                SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                ss.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(ss_SendCompleted);
                ss.EnableSsl = true;
                ss.Timeout = 10000;
                ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                ss.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("meuser", "mepassword");
                string userState = "test message1";
                ss.SendAsync(message, userState);
                lbl3.Enabled = true;
                lbl3.Visible = true;
                lbl3.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                lbl3.Text = "Sending email please wait";
                SendLogFile.Enabled = false;
            }

            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error sending message :" + errors);
            }
        }

        private void ss_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            timerdelay = 0;
            timer3.Start();
            String token = (string)e.UserState;
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Logger.Write("[{0}] Send canceled." + token);
                SendLogFile.Enabled = true;
            }
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                lbl3.Enabled = true;
                lbl3.Visible = true;
                lbl3.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                lbl3.Text = "There was a problem with sending the log file please try again later and check the log file for more information";
                Logger.Write("There was a problem with sending the log file please try again later and check the log file for more information :" + e.Error.ToString());
                SendLogFile.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SendLogFile.Enabled = true;
                message.Dispose();
                lbl3.Enabled = true;
                lbl3.Visible = true;
                lbl3.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                lbl3.Text = "Email have been sent successfully";
                Logger.Write("Attached log file have been emailed successfully");
                lbl1.BringToFront();
                lbl1.Visible = true;
                lbl1.Text = "The log file have been sent on: " + DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

The idea in general is to use the email like a server to transfer a push messages like updates. So when a user is downloading my program and run if any X minutes there a new email he will see it in the program like a new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea in general is to use the email like a server to transfer a push messages like updates. So when a user is downloading my program and run if any X minutes there a new email he will see it in the program like a new update.

Honestly, this sounds more like a job for a web service than an email client. You can have your client periodically consume a web service that publishes the latest update message. It will be much simpler for you to implement, and [there is a plethora of documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for doing so.

If you let web services do all the heavy lifting for you, you'll have less code to write, and have to worry less about making a secure, stable solution. Using email to do this seems very kludgy.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. However, could you add some details on how to setup a web service instead? Any tutorials that would explain how to do it, maybe add some code examples of that? By just saying "don't use that, use this" without any details, for me, isn't sufficient as an answer.

Comment: Indeed. I added a link. Thanks for the suggestion.